# Adding custom jars to pyspark in jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x, apache-kafka, pyspark, spark-streaming, jupyter-notebook

I am using the **Jupyter notebook with Pyspark** with the following **docker image**: [Jupyter all-spark-notebook](https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/tree/master/all-spark-notebook)

Now I would like to write a **pyspark streaming application which consumes messages from Kafka**. In the [Spark-Kafka Integration guide](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-integration.html) they describe how to deploy such an application using spark-submit (it requires linking an external jar - explanation is in *3. Deploying*). But since I am using Jupyter notebook I never actually run the `spark-submit` command, I assume it gets run in the back if I press execute.

In the `spark-submit` command you can specify some parameters, one of them is `-jars`, but it is not clear to me how I can set this parameter from the notebook (or externally via environment variables?). I am assuming I can link this external jar dynamically via the `SparkConf` or the `SparkContext` object. Has anyone experience on how to perform the linking properly from the notebook?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I've managed to get it working from within the jupyter notebook which is running form the all-spark container.

I start a python3 notebook in jupyterhub and overwrite the PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS flag as shown below. The Kafka consumer library was downloaded from the maven repository and put in my home directory /home/jovyan:

```
import os
os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = 
  '--jars /home/jovyan/spark-streaming-kafka-assembly_2.10-1.6.1.jar pyspark-shell'

import pyspark
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext

sc = pyspark.SparkContext()
ssc = StreamingContext(sc,1)

broker = "<my_broker_ip>"
directKafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, ["test1"],
                        {"metadata.broker.list": broker})
directKafkaStream.pprint()
ssc.start()
```

**Note:** Don't forget the pyspark-shell in the environment variables!

**Extension:** If you want to include code from spark-packages you can use the --packages flag instead. An example on how to do this in the all-spark-notebook can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/parente/c95fdaba5a9a066efaab)

Comment: Thanks. Just want to say that `broker` should be of format like: `"localhost:9092"`.

Comment: Were you ever able to do the same thing without downloading the jar and using `--packages` option (mentioned here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html) instead?

Comment: I am surprised that this actually worked for you.  I have to setup PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS in Dockerfile before container start.

Answer (score 9):

Indeed, there is a way to link it dynamically via the SparkConf object when you create the SparkSession, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46076881/4113770):

```py
spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("My App") \
    .config("spark.jars", "/path/to/jar.jar,/path/to/another/jar.jar") \
    .getOrCreate()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can run your jupyter notebook with the pyspark command by setting the relevant environment variables:

```
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=jupyter
export IPYTHON=1
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS="notebook --port=XXX --ip=YYY"
```

with XXX being the port you want to use to access the notebook and YYY being the ip address.

Now simply run pyspark and add --jars as a switch the same as you would spark submit

Comment: That's interesting.  Docker can set environment variables with `docker run -e `, but they can also get clobbered somewhere. The Dockerfile for all-spark-notebook uses env `SPARK_OPTS` but I have noticed that all-spark-notebook Toree (scala) was clobbering a `--driver-memory` setting as well as `--master` and using `local[2]` in a particular kernel.json file.  See, e.g., my post about some manual testing in https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/pull/144 .

Answer (score 1):

In case someone is the same as me: I tried all above solutions and none of them works for me. What I'm trying to do is to use [Delta Lake](https://delta.io/) in the Jupyter notebook.

Finally I can use `from delta.tables import *` by calling `SparkContext.addPyFile("/path/to/your/jar.jar")` first. Though in the spark official docs, it only mentions adding `.zip` or `.py` file, but I tried `.jar` and it worked perfectly.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/joshuacook/fbda6fdbec7dc6b0fb9bd7ed9953004a

Answer (score 0):

for working on jupyter-notebook with spark you need to give the location of the external jars before the creation of sparkContext object.
**pyspark --jars youJar** 
will create a sparkcontext with location of external jars